# Could the semicolon show a connector applies to multiple independent clauses?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

Pray consider the following examples of my proposed punctuation style.

1. Finally; add a sprinkle of sugar, and put the cake in the oven. [Both of these actions are the final step in this recipe—this should be clear.]
2. Gradually; the amount of wealth increased, but its value decreased. [I think "gradually" should *explicitly* apply to both of these clauses.]
3. In the end; few things are in our control, and we must accept this. ["In the end" is the linking word at the head of both sentences here.]

The aim is to make it explicit that the linking word applies to both clauses without repeating it. Are these example sentences acceptable? I find them quite readable.

Thank you for helping correct my mistakes and/or misunderstandings. I think it is a rare, precious sight—a single word followed by a semicolon.

Comment: Doesn’t work. A comma would do.

Comment: The semicolon is a medium-length pause, not an announcement. A colon can do what you want: it applies here and also here. If you want X to apply to (Y and Z) as in a mathematical distributive law, don't stop your reader with a "rare, precious sight," but with a readily understood arrow—the colon.